# Webflow Tiles Issue

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow, tiles2, apache-tiles

All,

We have implemented spring using tiles and everything works great so far.
I have 2 issues so far:

1)
I however do not like the idea of defining a new definition every time a new jsp is created.So i thought i would use 
wild card something like:

```
<definition name="*.*" extends="mainTemplate">
<put-attribute name="content" value="whatver"/>
</definition>
```

however this results in infinite loop whenever i try to render the jsp.

2)For some reason the login page (we are using spring security)which is outside the WEB-INF folder doesnt get the template styling applied , do we have to do anything special for login page to extend the template.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks